# SQL Query works fine in management studio but not from ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to run the following query against a MS SQL 2008 database in an ASP test program. The query works just fine in the 'Server Management Studio', and I can connect to the database from the ASP program without any problems. However, when I put it all together, I get the following error:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

/test.asp, line 59
```

Line 59 conforms to the last line in the following snippet:

```
set c = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
c.Open "PROVIDER=sqloledb;SERVER=DESKTOP-VM-WIN7\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=ExamDB;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;"
set r = c.Execute("DECLARE @session_id uniqueidentifier; " &_
              "SET @session_id = 'BFAABD2A-4717-4619-8CF6-E20009B97E8F'; " &_
              "DECLARE @exam_id uniqueidentifier; " &_
              "SET @exam_id = (SELECT exam_id " &_
              "                FROM sessions " &_
              "                WHERE session_id = @session_id); " &_
              "CREATE TABLE #exam (concept_title nvarchar(50), " &_
              "                    concept_description xml, " &_
              "                    concept_questions xml); " &_
              "DECLARE @concept_id uniqueidentifier; " &_
              "DECLARE concept_cursor CURSOR FOR " &_
              "SELECT concept_id " &_
              "FROM exams " &_
              "WHERE exam_id = @exam_id; " &_
              "OPEN concept_cursor; " &_
              "FETCH NEXT FROM concept_cursor INTO @concept_id; " &_
              "WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 " &_
              "BEGIN " &_
              "    INSERT #exam " &_
              "    SELECT concepts.concept_title, " &_
              "           concepts.concept_description, " &_
              "           (SELECT questions.question_title, " &_
              "                   questions.question_description, " &_
              "                   questions.question_answer, " &_
              "                   questions.question_difficulty " &_
              "            FROM questions " &_
              "            INNER JOIN concepts " &_
              "            ON questions.question_id = concepts.question_id AND concepts.concept_id = @concept_id " &_
              "            ORDER BY concepts.question_order " &_
              "            FOR XML PATH('question'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) " &_
              "    FROM concepts " &_
              "    WHERE concepts.concept_id = @concept_id AND concept_title IS NOT NULL; " &_
              "    FETCH NEXT FROM concept_cursor INTO @concept_id; " &_
              "END; " &_
              "SELECT * FROM #exam " &_
              "FOR XML PATH('concept'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('exam'), TYPE; " &_
              "CLOSE concept_cursor; " &_
              "DEALLOCATE concept_cursor; " &_
              "DROP TABLE #exam; ")
Response.Write(r(0))
```

Is there something obviously wrong? Also, is there a good approach for debugging problems of this nature? Thanks!

Comment: the thing that is obviously wrong is you are using dynamic TSQL and not a stored proc!

Comment: Try wrapping all the SQL in `BEGIN...END`.

Comment: I wouldn't think the BEGIN...END will do anything. Can you check the r.ActiveConnection.Errors collection to see if there are additional errors from the provider(s)? The one you posted doesn't obviously correspond to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually get this error when a field name is misspelt.  Double check your SQL.

If you are **absolutely sure** that your SQL is correct, see if `SET NOCHECK ON` will help.

Please consider the advices in the comments and do it with stored procedures.  Avoid yourself a load of pain.

Comment: The 'SET NOCHECK ON' seemed to do the trick. I think I'll take everyone's advice though and use a stored procedure. Thanks!